# Sums and Products of Ideals in a Commutative Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring, $I$ and ideal and $a,b$ two elements of the ring. It says in my lecture notes :

$$ (I+Ra)(I+Rb)=I^2+aI+bI+Rab $$

I'm not disagreeing to this but I'd like to know if it's hard to prove because the only trivial statement I can make is that the left side is a subset of the right side.

$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
(I+Ra)(I+Rb) & = & \lbrace (i_1+r_1a)(i_2+r_2b) \mid i_1,i_2 \in I \quad r_1,r_2 \in R \rbrace \\
& = &  \lbrace i_1i_2 + i_2r_1a + i_1r_2b + r_1r_2ab \mid i_1,i_2 \in I \quad r_1,r_2 \in R \rbrace \\
& \subset & \lbrace i_1i_2 + i_3a + i_4b + rab \mid i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4 \in I \quad r \in R \rbrace \\
& = & I^2+aI+bI+Rab \end {array}  $$

Obviously my lecturor's claim is that my $\subset$ symbol can actually be replaced by an $=$ sign.

It seems to me like $I^2+aI+bI+Rab$ is a lot bigger than $(I+Ra)(I+Rb)$ since it a priori has more freedom as my equation seems to suggest. For instance, when $i_1$, $i_2$ and $i_3$ are chosen, why should there be an $r_1$ such that $i_2r_1a=i_3a$ when we know nothing about divisibility or invertibility of the elements ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the language of rings (and modules), whenever $AB$ is found, it usually means the set of all sums of elements of the form $ab$, with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Instead of $A\{b\}$ one usually writes $Ab$, but in this case sums are not necessary, because $a_1b+\dots+a_nb=(a_1+\dots+a_n)b$, *provided* $A$ is closed under sums.

If $I$ is an ideal, then clearly it is closed under sums; hence
$$
Ia=\{xa:x\in I\}
$$
However, if $I$ and $J$ are ideals, then
$$
IJ=
\Bigl\{\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k:n\ge0, x_k\in I, y_k\in J, k=1,\dots,n\Bigr\}
$$
not to be confused with the set $\{xy:x\in I,y\in J\}$ which is generally not even closed under sums.

It's easy to see that $IJ$ is the ideal *generated* by the products $xy$, with $x\in I$ and $y\in J$. In the case of $Ra$, this is exactly the set of products $ra$, for $r\in R$, because $R$ is closed under sums.

With this interpretation (which is the one implicitly used in ring theory, unless the contrary is explicitly mentioned), if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are ideals, then
$$
(A+B)C=AC+BC
$$
as you can easily prove. In particular
$$
(I+Ra)(I+Rb)=I^2+RaI+IRb+RaRb
$$
Now $RaI=aI$, because
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(r_ka)x_k=a\sum_{k=1}^n(r_kx_k)\in aI
$$
and the converse inclusion is obvious (if $R$ has identity).

You can prove similarly that $(Ra)(Rb)=Rab$. So we get
$$
(I+Ra)(I+Rb)=I^2+aI+bI+Rab
$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

Careful; the product of two ideals does not consist of all products of elements of the two ideals, but of all *sums* of products of elements of the two ideals. That is, it is the ideal *generated* by all products of elements of the two ideals. So $z\in (I+Ra)(I+Rb)$ if and only if there exist $n\in\Bbb{N}$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in I+Ra$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n\in I+Rb$ such that $z=\sum_{k=1}^nx_ky_k$.

Comment: Do you mean that $(I+Ra)(I+Rb)$ stands for $\lbrace \Sigma_{k=1}^{n} (i_{1,k}+r_{1,k}a)(i_{2,k}+r_{2,k}b) \mid (i_{1,k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}},(i_{2,k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \in I^\mathbb{N} \quad (r_{1,k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}},(r_{2,k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \in R^\mathbb{N} \quad n\in \mathbb{N}  \rbrace$ ?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, I just didn't feel like writing that out.